# PHP unable to print mysql_query() result

Tags: php, mysql

I have code

```
$email = "jb@tlb.com";    
$row = mysql_query("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT email FROM accounts WHERE email='".$email."');");
echo $row[0];
```

However, nothing is echoed.

This is strange because something is being returned because, later in the code I have a function that is CALLED:

```
if ( $row[0] == 0 ) { echo "Email address is available<br>";};
```

However: this is strange because when i put the SAME CODE into mySQL database command prompt:

[image]

It clearly returns 1 or TRUE.

The mysql_query is returning 0 when the same exact command in mysql command prompt returns 1.  Further: I am unable to echo the result for debugging purposes.

EDIT:  Please not, the regular mySQL command is returning this and ONLY this:
[image]

EDIT: Here is there entire database:
[image]

Comment: have you tried doing `print_r($row)` to see what all is being returned?

Comment: Yeah that just gives me a Resource id #5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL query gives you a ressource. After that you have to fetch the data with mysql_fetch_assoc or mysql_fetch_row or something else for example. But its better to use prepared statements with [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/de/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php) to get more security.

```
$email = "jb@tlb.com";    
$res = mysql_query("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT email FROM accounts WHERE email='".myql_real_escape_string($email)."')");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
echo $row['email'];
```

Answer to your question:

```
$email = "jb@tlb.com";    
$res = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM accounts WHERE email='".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."')");
$numRows = mysql_num_rows($res);

if($rowRows > 0) {
    echo "Record Available";
}
```

Comment: Since i'm doing SELECT EXISTS its only going to return true or false right?

Comment: Hmm if you want to check if the data exists its easier to make a count SELECT COUNT(id) as countout FROM ... WHERE ... if row['countout'] is bigger then 0 its a dataset available.

Comment: I tried 



   $email = "jb@tlb.com";
   $res = mysql_query("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT email FROM accounts WHERE email='".$email."')");
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
   echo $row['email'];

However i got errors:

Notice: Undefined index: email in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/TLB/create_account.php

Comment: Your second code snippet is giving me error: Notice: Undefined index: countout in

Comment: Try that with mysql_num_rows then you get the number of all counted rows.

Comment: function not defined : Fatal error: Call to undefined function myql_real_escape_string() in

Comment: Perhaps its better if you first read about MySQL and PHP and how it works. There was an "s" missing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually retrieve the result set from the query.  `mysql_query()` just returns a resource handle for a successful select.  You then need to fetch the results using `mysql_fetch_*` class of functions. Alternatively, you can use `mysql_num_rows()` to determine the number of rows returned in the result set.

In this case it is really senseless to wrap your actual query into a subquery.  Just run your select and determine the number of rows:

```
$email = "jb@tlb.com";    
$result = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM accounts WHERE email='".$email . "'");
if($result) {
    $row_count = mysql_num_rows($result);
    echo $row_count;
}
```

Also, you should not be writing new code using `mysql_*` functions, as these are deprecated.  I would suggest `mysqli` or `PDO` extensions instead.

Comment: It is SELECT EXISTS though which returns true or false though correct?

Comment: @user3677286 Yes. It would. But why do you care about that sort of wrapper? You will either have a row count of `0` or `> 0` in the result set.  That is the same thing and removes use of subselect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like

```
while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($row)) 
{ 
    echo $r[0];                                 
}
```

after that code.

Let me know.